# How to solve 2 hours receiving delay in outlook.com?

Tags: outlook.com

Sometimes Outlook.com receives email after 2 hours. I mean email should receive at 10 pm but it was received at 12:06AM (Next Day).

How to solve 2 hours receiving delay in outlook.com ?

I am referring to the email website called outlook.com not office 365.